# Divi Gallery customization (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, image-gallery, divi

I did a website with Divi and I use the divi gallery.

I want to customize the gallery a bit, but I don't know how to do it.
The Images are here in my case "projects", each image one project. So if I click now, the thumbnail image is opening in a Lightbox as a big image. When I go left or right I see the other projects of the gallery.
So far so good. Now my question is.. how can I customize the gallery, that it shows me instead of other projects, more images of the clicked project in a lightbox. So the thumbnail image would be a preview of a project (f.E. building a chair), and if you click on it the lightbox will open and you can switch between the images of the different views of the chair.
You know what I mean?

[image: Preview]

the Website is: wip.melsinter.ch/projekte

Does someone knows how I can customize that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're asking.

You can do this by making each of your main images its own gallery. Create a row with 3 columns, for example. Add a Gallery module to the first column. In the module, select all of the images for your gallery, and then arrange so that the first image is the one you want them to click.

Set Gallery Settings >> Content >> Images >> Image Count to 1. Under elements, turn off the pagination and title/caption (unless you want them viewable on all images. This will allow the lightbox to have it's own slider for your gallery.

Duplicate this module for the other columns in the row, and change the images. Then duplicate the row as needed (changing the images for each module).